# Is there a way to detect missing mod requirements for Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

So, there are various tools to manage the mods I've installed (say, Nexus Mod Manager or Steam workshop), there are mods to set the load order in a smart way (BOSS).

But what I'm missing is a tool to show me what mods that are required (listed as Masters in the mods I'm loading) but that I've not loaded yet, given that Skyrim shows me this in the delightful way of crashing to the desktop on loading the main menu and not providing any diagnostics.

Is there a way to figure out which mod is causing the crash, or which requirements haven't been filled?

Comment: Pretty sure this can be seen as a software recommendation.  Think you might be able to reword it to focus on the problem(s) you're attempting to solve?

Comment: "Is there a way to figure out which mod is causing the crash, or which requirements haven't been filled?" Check your logs...

Comment: @FinnRayment sure, they can be found by going to about:blank in your web browser because logging doesn't start until after the mods have been loaded, and the game crashes during the loading :)

Comment: @Frank You're right, bleh, blame posting when I should be sleeping. I think Robotnik's version is better, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mod Organizer and Wrye Bash will both display missing and present Masters for mods.

If you don't want to make the switch to MO (though I'd recommend it) and you don't need a bashed patch, it would still be worthwhile to download Wrye to just run every now and then to check dependencies.